# Sifting needle (String array) through haystack (larger String array) in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to return the index position of where in the haystack 
 array the needle array occurs and -1 if otherwise. For example if String `haystackArray = [red, blue, green]` and String `needleArray = [blue, green]` it should return a 1 for the 1 index position of the haystack that the needle occurs.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
    public static int FindSequence(String[] haystack, String[] needle)
    {
        int numInSequence = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        if(haystack.length == 0 || needle.length == 0)  
            return -1;
        if(needle.length > haystack.length)
            return -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < haystack.length-1; i++) //for the length of haystack
        {
            if(needle[0].equals(haystack[i]))//if the first item in needle is equivalent to this particular item in haystack...
            {
                numInSequence = i;
                numInSequence+=1;
                for(int j = 1; j < needle.length-1; j++, numInSequence++){ //for the remaining length of the needle... 
                    if(needle[j].equals(haystack[numInSequence])){ //checks to see if the next item in needle is equivalent to the next item in haystack and if this 
                        counter++;
         if((needle[needle.length-1]).equals(haystack[numInSequence])){ // if the last item in needle is equivalent to an item in haystack...
                            return numInSequence - counter - 1; // return our desired index
                        }
                    }     
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
        } 
        return -10;
    }
```

For some reason, pretty much any array tests I try, I get the -10 returned. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: adjust the indentation of  if((needle[needle.length-1]).equals(haystack[numInSequence])){.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the loop condition to

```
for(int i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++)
```

and

```
 for(int j = 1; j < needle.length; j++, numInSequence++){
```

With your current current code, you are skipping the last index.

Also, if j < needle.length -1, how can it enter your

```
if((needle[needle.length-1]).equals(haystack[numInSequence])){
```

and return `return numInSequence - counter - 1;`. That is the source of the bug.

To give an example, if there are 10 elements in the array, you have indices from 0-9. And you are checking < 9 instead of < 10. So, the index 9 is not checked by your code.